# Ajuda em javascript

Tags: javascript, script, countdown

Como faço para esse script executar em 10 segundos ??

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

function simulateClick(x, y) {

var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, x, y, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
document.elementFromPoint(x, y).dispatchEvent(clickEvent);

}
simulateClick(1176, 435);
</script>
```

A ideia seria colocar um countdown nele, alguém sabe ?

Comment: `setTimeout(simulateClick(1176,435), 10000);`

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira Isso faria ele executar imediatamente, só o resultado (`undefined`) seria passado pro `setTimeout`. Melhor seria `setTimeout(function() { simulateClick(1176,435); }, 10000);`

Comment: @mgibsonbr funcionou perfeito, valeu

Comment: @mgibsonbr verdade, isso que da escrever na pressa. Escreve uma resposta aí pra ganhar pontos de internet ;)

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira Blz, fiz isso. E ainda aprendi uma coisa nova rsrs (não sabia que o `setTimeout` aceitava argumentos adicionais - nos *browsers* recentes pelo menos)

Answer (score 5):

A função [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) pode ser usada para invocar uma função após X milissegundos:

```
var timeoutID = setTimeout(simulateClick, 10000, 1176, 435);
```

O primeiro parâmetro é a função que será chamada, o segundo o número de milissegundos a esperar (10s = 10000ms). Os parâmetros adicionais são passados diretamente à função, ou seja, é quase o mesmo que fazer:

```
setTimeout(function() { simulateClick(1176,435); }, 10000);
```

(**Nota:** caso você queira dar suporte ao IE9 ou anterior use sempre esse segundo formato, pois o primeiro não é suportado)

O valor de retorno pode ser ignorado, se você não precisar dele. Ele é usado caso se queira *cancelar* a chamada da função antes que ela ocorra, via `clearTimeout(timeoutID)`.